# visual studio richtext box not displaying text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, richtextbox

I am using Visual studio 2017 and I have a RichTextBox that doesn't display text when I set it:

```
public void ArduinoDataRecived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{ 
    SerialPort TempSerial = (SerialPort)sender;
    ConsoleTextBox.AppendText(TempSerial.ReadLine());
}
```

The code runs with no errors and whenever I call the `MessageBox.Show(ConsoleTextBox.text)` it displays the text that the serial port sent and yet the text box doesn't display it.

If I have a completely different method that set the text then it works?

Comment: Show the code pls!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a threading issue. Here's a copy-paste from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms143556(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx):

> The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is
>   received from the SerialPort object. Because this event is raised on a
>   secondary thread, and not the main thread, attempting to modify some
>   elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a
>   threading exception. If it is necessary to modify elements in the main
>   Form or Control, post change requests back using Invoke, which will do
>   the work on the proper thread.

P.S. Before using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort be sure [to read this](http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport). [And this](http://zachsaw.blogspot.com/2010/07/net-serialport-woes.html). Unfortunately, the problems are still not fixed in .NET 4.5.2. Not long ago I ported my serial comm code from C# to C++ to make my software work reliably for all users. But if it works on your machine, and you're not working on a commercial software, System.IO.Ports.SerialPort might still be fine for you.